# How do I perform a Discrete FFT by hand?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform, education, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

I have understood the theory behind the Fourier Transform, but when I look at the formula on the internet there are multiple variables that are not explained. I know it is probably standard notation for this but I am self-taught and do not know what they are.

For example, how would I perform the FFT of [6, 7, 8]?

I am familiar with calculus and other topics, it is just this I'm struggling with.

Comment: In standard notation $X_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ne^{-\frac{i2\pi}{N}kn}$ your example has $N=3$, then just fill in the equation. Otherwise your question is not clear. Note that FFT is a special efficient calculation scheme for the generic DFT and not really meaningful for only 3 samples.

Comment: Where little n is 0, 1, 2 and k is?

Comment: If you have 3 samples for $x[n]$ you get 3 samples in 'the other' domain, i.e. $X[k]$ and for each fixed $k$ you must do the entire summation in order to calculate that sample. For electronics engineers $x$ is usually in the time domain and $X$ in the frequency domain.

Comment: Just to be sure, in my case, k would be 0, 1, 2?

Comment: Yes, in your case $k$ would be 0, 1, 2.

Comment: [Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/show-how-to-do-fft-by-hand) are  are some explanations on  how to do FFT by hand.